# What is the difference between @StateObject and @ObservedObject in child views in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, observedobject

I created a Model like this:

```
class TestModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var num: Int = 0
}
```

Model is be used in "Home" view and "Home"s child view "HomeSub"

```
struct Home: View {
    
    @StateObject var model = TestModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(content: {
            NavigationLink(destination: HomeSub(model: model)) { Text("\(model.num)") }
        })
    }
}
```

```
struct HomeSub: View {
   //1
    @StateObject var model = TestModel()
   //2
    @ObservedObject var model = TestModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(model.num)")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
            Button("Add") {
                model.num += 1
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: model.num, perform: { value in
            print("homeSub: \(value)")
        })
        
    }
}
```

In HomeSub view, what is the difference between 1 and 2?
When I run the project, they have exactly the same behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've written it, both `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject` are doing the same thing in the child view.  But, neither is correct because they are unnecessarily creating a new `TestModel` just to toss it and replace it with the one being passed in.

The correct way to write the child view is:

```
@ObservedObject var model: TestModel
```

In this case, no initial value is assigned to `model` in the child view, which means the caller will have to provide it.  This is exactly what you want.  One *source of truth* which is the `model` in the parent view.

Also, state variables (both `@State` and `@StateObject`) should be `private` to a view and should always be marked with `private`.  If you had done this:

```
@StateObject private var model = TestModel()
```

in the child view, then you wouldn't have been able to pass the model from the parent view and you would have seen that only `@ObservedObject` can be used in this case.

---

Upon further testing, it seems that Swift/SwiftUI avoids creating the `TestModel` in the child view when it is written as `@ObservedObject var model = TestModel()`, but that syntax is still misleading to the reader and it should still be written as `@ObservedObject var model: TestModel` because that makes it clear that `model` is being initialized from somewhere else (that is, from the parent view).

Answer (score 0):

They are used almost interchangeably and in your setup create 2 instances of the same Model.

`@StateObject`'s lifecycle is managed by SwiftUI, it is only available in iOS 14+.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject

`@ObservableObject`'s lifecycle is managed by the developer (Can sometimes be reinitialized unintentionally with a `View` refresh because it is supposed to come from a Parent `View`), it is available in iOS 13+.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is better to use `@ObservedObject` as you are injecting the value from the parent. `@StateObject` is designed to hold an object independently on the View (it's lifecycle is managed by SwiftUI). It is not needed here because of the injection.